# AJAX Toolkit execute Apex method with inner classes

Tags: apex, javascript, ajax-toolkit

I have a `Visualforce Page` where I use the `AJAX Toolkit` to execute `Apex` methods. In my `Apex Class` I have this POC method:

```
WebService static ParametersWrapper testWebserviceMethod(ParametersWrapper params) {
    System.debug(params);
    return params;
}
```

And these inner classes:

```
global class ParametersWrapper {
    webService String testString;
    webService List<TupleWrapper> tuples;
}

global class TupleWrapper {
    webService String key;
    webService String value;
}
```

In the `Visualforce Page` I have written a `JavaScript` function which basically contains these line of code:

```
// Loop over the tuples and create a TupleWrapper object from the XML.
var tuples = [];
$.each(tupleList, function(index, item) {
    var tuple = new sforce.Xml('TupleWrapper');
    tuple.key = item.key;
    tuple.value = item.value;
    tuples.push(tuple);
}

// Create a ParametersWrapper object from the XML and pass in the data
var params = new sforce.Xml('ParametersWrapper');
params.testString = 'This is a Test';
params.tuples = tuples;

sforce.apex.execute('ApexClassName', 'testWebserviceMethod', {params: params});
```

When I debug the action, `testString` is passed along to the method in the `Apex Class`. But the tuples all come back with `key: null` and `value: null`. The `amount` is in fact correct. So when I pass along 10 tuples, than 10 tuple pairs will all be null for the key and the value variable.

Does any one has any idea how I can use an inner class object with a List of an inner class? Or maybe a workaround?